# How to logout chat in QuickBlox API

Tags: android, logout, quickblox

I have been checking the SDK Manual (http://sdk.quickblox.com/android/) but I didn't figure out how to logout from chat.

I want to LogOut because API saves your pending messages when your are logged out.

Anyone has an idea about how to do that?

Comment: I have found the solution in the following link: http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/XMPPConnection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the **shutdown(Presence unavailablePresence)** method in **XMPPConnection** class

Answer (score 1):

Here are the codes from Quickblox

```
boolean isLoggedIn = chatService.isLoggedIn();
if(!isLoggedIn){
    return;
}

chatService.logout(new QBEntityCallbackImpl() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        // success

        chatService.destroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(final List list) {

    }
});
```

hope this helps :)